# mysql insert id comparing between two tables

Tags: mysql, insert, compare

I've got two tables:
[image]

I want to insert the post_id from table1 to media_id from table2 where in both tables the field meta_value is the same. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it using update with join

```
update table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t1.meta_value = t2.meta_value
set t2.media_id = t1.post_id
```

If you want to do it for a particular `meta_value` you may add a where condition at the end as

```
where t2.meta_value = '{your value}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this query:

```
UPDATE table2
SET t2.media_id = t1.post_id
FROM table2 t2 inner join table1 t1 on (t1.meta_value = t2.meta_value);
```